# Unity Android speech recognition plugin seems not to be working

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, plugins, speech-recognition

I built my Android game which includes a Java plugin made by myself in order to implement speech recognition (in Spanish). This recognition can start by touching a button on the screen and can end by stopping touching the button. The result of the speech recognition is shown in a text above the button.

The problem is that, when I touch the button, talk, and release the button, nothing seems to happen. It had already happened to me using similar plugins like this one: https://github.com/j1mmyto9/speech-and-text-unity-ios-android

Here is all the code I use for the speech recognition feature:

**Java plugin:**

```
package com.example.unityandroidplswork;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class STTPlugin {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final String TAG = "SpeechRecognitionPlugin";
    private Activity activity;
    private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;
    private SpeechRecognitionResultListener resultListener;

    public STTPlugin(Activity activity) {

        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void startSpeechRecognition(SpeechRecognitionResultListener listener) {
        if (SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(activity.getApplicationContext())) {
            resultListener = listener;
            if (speechRecognizer == null) {
                speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(activity.getApplicationContext());
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 10);
            speechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
            Log.d(TAG, "Escuchando...");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Reconocimiento no disponible.");
        }

    }

    public void stopSpeechRecognition() {
        if (speechRecognizer != null) {
            speechRecognizer.stopListening();
        }
    }

    private String[] processRecognitionResults(ArrayList<String> results) {
        return results.toArray(new String[results.size()]);
    }

    public void handleActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            if (resultListener != null) {
                String[] resultsArray = processRecognitionResults(results);
                resultListener.onResults(resultsArray);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface SpeechRecognitionResultListener {
        void onResults(String[] results);
    }


}
```

**C# script which calls the plugin:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class SpeechRecog : MonoBehaviour
{

    private AndroidJavaObject speechRecPlugin;
    public TextMeshProUGUI textofresult;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        AndroidJavaObject activity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        speechRecPlugin = new AndroidJavaObject("com.example.unityandroidplswork.STTPlugin", activity);
    }

    public void StartSpeechRecognition() {
        AndroidJavaObject speechResultListener = new AndroidJavaObject("com.example.unityandroidplswork.STTPlugin$SpeechRecognitionResultListener", this);
     
        speechRecPlugin.Call("startSpeechRecognition", speechResultListener);
    }

    public void StopSpeechRecognition() {
        speechRecPlugin.Call("stopSpeechRecognition");
    }

    private void ProcessRecognitionResults(string[] results) {
        string recognizedtext = "";
        foreach(string result in results) {
            Debug.Log("Result: " + result);
            recognizedtext += result + " ";
        }
        textofresult.text = recognizedtext;
        //process here for sure
        //ProcessCommands(results)
    } 


    private class SpeechRecognitionResultListener : AndroidJavaProxy {

        private SpeechRecog plugin;

        public SpeechRecognitionResultListener(SpeechRecog plugin) : base("com.example.unityandroidplswork.STTPlugin$SpeechRecognitionResultListener") {
            this.plugin = plugin;
        }

        public void onResults(string[] results) {
            plugin.ProcessRecognitionResults(results);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <application>
    <activity 
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
      android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>   
  </application>
</manifest>
```

**C# script for button handling:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class VoiceClickHandler : MonoBehaviour
{

    public UnityEvent upEvent;
    public UnityEvent downEvent;

    void OnMouseDown() {
        Debug.Log("Down");
        downEvent?.Invoke();
    }

    void OnMouseUp() {
        Debug.Log("Up");
        upEvent?.Invoke();
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if the issue is related to the code since, as I said before, it has happended to me before with other solutions, but just in case I'm missing something.

I checked my code again after seeing the problem and solved some errors that I hadn't realize before, but even so it's still the same. I also made sure the application has microphone permission enabled and checked the project configuration, but it seems to be alright.

I also tried using open-source speech recognition modules such as CMUSphinx, but it didn't work either.

**UPDATE**

Checking the logs, I found that each time I touch the button I get the error:

AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.unityandroidplswork.STTPlugin

Each time I release the button I get a similar error too, so I suppose that somehow the plugin is not being detected.
My plugin is a JAR file made from the provided Java code, and this JAR file is inside Assets/Plugins/Android in my Unity project. Why is it not being found?